# mongoose is throwing error of Schema hasn't been registered in next.js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, next.js13, mongoose-populate

I have just started to use next.js and whenever I call api which has reference to another document, mongoose throws an error to me stating that "Schema hasn't been registered for model".

Here is my code.

**Models**

**Task.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TaskModel = () => {
  const schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const taskSchema = new schema(
    {
      taskName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      empId: {
        type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Employee",
        required: true,
      },
      adminId: {
        type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Admin",
        required: true,
      },
      deptId: {
        type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Department",
        required: true,
      },
      deadline: {
        type: String,
      },
      status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      completedDate: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
      },
      completionStatus: {
        type: String,
        default: "Assigned",
      },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );

  return mongoose.models.Task ?? mongoose.model("Task", taskSchema);
};

export default TaskModel;
```

**employee.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const EmployeeModel = () => {
  const schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const employeeSchema = new schema({
    empName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    empEmail: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    department: {
      type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Department",
      required: true,
      // type:String
    },
    document: {
      type: String,
    },
    loginStatus: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  });

  return mongoose.models.Employee ?? mongoose.model("Employee", employeeSchema);
};

export default EmployeeModel;
```

**db.js** (For connecting the app with mongoDB)

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

import TestModel from "@/models/test";
import TaskModel from "@/models/task";
import AdminModel from "@/models/admin";
import EmployeeModel from "@/models/employee";
import DepartmentModel from "@/models/department";

if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1) {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
}
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

export const db = {
  Test: TestModel,
  Task: TaskModel,
  Admin: AdminModel,
  Employee: EmployeeModel,
  Department: DepartmentModel,
};
```

**getTask/route.jsx**

```
import { db } from "@/helpers/db";

const Task = db.Task();
export const GET = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await Task.find().populate("empId");
    return Response.json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return Response.json(error, { status: 422 });
  }
};
```

**dashboard/page.jsx**

```
"use client";
import style from "./page.module.css";
import Api from "./api";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState("");
  const [finalData, setFinalData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const apiCall = async () => {
      const taskdata = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/task/getTask");
      const actualTaskData = await taskdata.json();
      console.log(actualTaskData);
      return actualTaskData;
    };
    const apires = apiCall();
    setFinalData(apires);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Here is the image of my error
[image: here is the image of my error]

I am attaching the folder structure for reference

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will have to register the `Employee` model to use it in the `populate` method. This is untested but try:

```js
const Task = db.Task();
const Employee = db.Employee(); //< Instantiate an Employee model
export const GET = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await Task.find().populate({ path: "empId", model: Employee });//< Explicitly use the Employee model here
    return Response.json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return Response.json(error, { status: 422 });
  }
};
```